# Favorites from Windows 7 disappeared in windows 8.1 installation

Tags: windows, windows-8.1-upgrade

Installed windows 8.1 over windows 7, where are my favorites from windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed on the top on Windows 7 everything is going to be erased. If you upgraded from Win 8.1 to Win 7 and chose option keep your personal files (bookmarks are not part of your personal files, unless if they are saved on your desktop files/folders) Personal file are Users desktop file (documents, photos, music, movies,etc) Microsoft suggests before upgrade, back up everything, hope this was helpful. More information

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-from-windows-7-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

### Browsing Sync Service

First off and the easiest way to retrieve your favorites is if you have a data sync service like a Google Account with Google Chrome. You can simply login to your Google Account and sync your favorites. If not, there are still other ways.

---

### Windows.old Recovery

You can easily recover your files and other data including your bookmarks/favorites if these conditions apply as stated on Microsoft's website ([Retrieve files from the Windows.old folder](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-files-upgrade-windows-old)).

> If you choose to “Keep nothing” when you upgrade to Windows 8.1, or if you reset, refresh, or re-install Windows, your personal files are temporarily saved to the Windows.old folder for 28 days (unless you formatted your hard drive before installing). If you decide you want some or all of these files back, you can usually retrieve them from this folder.

So, If you did not format your hard drive and it has not been 28 days since you have installed Windows 8.1, you're in luck. You can simply go ahead and use the automatic diagnostic tool (provided in the link) which will retrieve your personal data and put it back in place. If you don't want that, you can go ahead and recover the bookmarks manually. Every browser works differently in terms of bookmark saving location and importing options so I'll list the three most popular Windows browsers and how to recover each of their bookmarks.

**Google Chrome**

1. Navigate to: `C:\Windows.old\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
2. Copy the Bookmarks file onto your Desktop.
3. Open up Google Chrome Control Menu
4. Head over to Bookmarks > Bookmark manager
   [image]
5. Click Organize > Import bookmarks from HTML file > Open the Bookmarks file in your Desktop.
   [image]

**Firefox**

1. Navigate to: `C:\Windows.old\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\jy9f8hk8.default\bookmarkbackups`
2. Copy the most recent bookmarks JSON file to the desktop. Format: bookmarks-yyyy-mm-dd_x.json
3. Click Firefox Menu > Bookmarks [image]
4. Click Import and Backup > Restore > Choose File... > Open the Bookmarks JSON file in your Desktop.
   [image]

**Internet Explorer**

1. Navigate to: `C:\Windows.old\Users\<username>\`
2. Copy the Favorites folder and paste it on the desktop.
3. Navigate to your current user folder: `C:\Users\<username>\`
4. Delete your Favorites folder (**WARNING**: This will delete ***ALL*** your current favorites)
5. Cut and Paste the Favorites folder from your desktop to this directory (`C:\Users\<username>\`).

---

### Data Recovery

If none of the above apply to you and your favorites are worth the hassle, you can try your luck with data recovery and hope your favorites data is no overridden (All data remains intact even after deletion until formatted with 0s and 1s or unless overridden by current data). There are some free data recovery software you can try out or you can find other professional paid software to help you recover the data. Here are [17 Free Data Recovery Software Tools](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm).

Good luck.